# CSS loader/Progress spinner Material angular 2+

Tags: html, css, material-design, angular-material2

I'm trying to imitate the [loader/Progress spinner](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview) from angular material. So far I made the following component. But I don't know why the length of the dash isn't changing.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

// demo-specific
.showbox {
position: absolute;
   
}
// end demo-specific

.loader {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  &:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
  }
}

.circular {
  animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: dash 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke: #0057e7;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 20, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 100, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -35px;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 200, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -125px;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="showbox">
          <div class="loader">
            <svg class="circular" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
                <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
              </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem to me looks like it is going straight from 0% to 50%, where are the example they transition from 0% to 10% etc etc etc. Simply include more steps between 0 and 50%.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code to achieve that.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:500);

*
{
  font-family: 'RobotoDraft', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.material_block
{
  width: 580px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  margin: auto;
}

.spinner
{
  -webkit-animation: rotation 1.35s linear infinite;
  animation: rotation 1.35s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation
{
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotation
{
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
}

.circle
{
  stroke-dasharray: 180;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-animation: turn 1.35s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: turn 1.35s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes turn
{
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 180;
  }

  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 45;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 180;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(450deg);
    transform: rotate(450deg);
  }
}

@keyframes turn
{
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 180;
  }

  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 45;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 180;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(450deg);
    transform: rotate(450deg);
  }
}

svg:nth-child(1){stroke:#e51c23;}
svg:nth-child(2){stroke:#e91e63;}
svg:nth-child(3){stroke:#9c27b0;}
svg:nth-child(4){stroke:#673ab7;}
svg:nth-child(5){stroke:#3f51b5;}
svg:nth-child(6){stroke:#5677fc;}
svg:nth-child(7){stroke:#03a9f4;}
svg:nth-child(8){stroke:#00bcd4;}
svg:nth-child(9){stroke:#009688;}
svg:nth-child(10){stroke:#259b24;}
svg:nth-child(11){stroke:#8bc34a;}
svg:nth-child(12){stroke:#cddc39;}
svg:nth-child(13){stroke:#ffeb3b;}
svg:nth-child(14){stroke:#ffc107;}
svg:nth-child(15){stroke:#ff9800;}
svg:nth-child(16){stroke:#ff5722;}
svg:nth-child(17){stroke:#795548;}
svg:nth-child(18){stroke:#9e9e9e;}
svg:nth-child(19){stroke:#607d8b;}
```

```html
<div class="material_block">
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
</div>
```